# Leaflet wrong coordinates if no bounds exist

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, gis

I'm using Leaflet JS and I want my map acts like if its a circular map, so if I go from Europe to the east, I'd like to appear in USA, then in Asia and finally in Europe again.

I have set `maxBounds` attribute to `null` (the default value) and it works, but the map gives me wrong longitude values as -530 degrees.

Is any direct way to get the right values or should I have to recalculate them if they go beyond a limit?

Thanks.

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-worldcopyjump

Comment: @ghybs : you've got the solution. If you post it, i set is as valid